# Creating a randomly generated graph matrix in C++

Tags: c++, graph, segmentation-fault

So, I've been desperately trying to make this randomly generated graph matrix, but I cannot make it work and I don't know why, getting segfault all the time. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int graph_size = 4;

int main(void)
{
    bool** graph;
    srand(time(0));

    graph = new bool*[graph_size];
    for(int i=0; i<graph_size; i++)
    {
        graph[i] = new bool[graph_size];
        for(int j=0; j<graph_size; j++)
        {
            if(i==j){graph[i][j]=false;}
            else{ 
                graph[j][i] = (((rand()%100)/100.0) < 0.19);
                graph[i][j] = graph[j][i]; 
            }

            cout << graph[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try creating the full matrix outside the loop. Inside the second loop you are accessing with graph[j][i] but it does not exist yet! Also you forgot to delete the graph, you may instead use a 2D std::array here `std::array<std::array<bool, graph_size>, graph_size> graph`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is when you do `graph[j][i]` when `j` is bigger than `i`. When that happens, you didn't allocate the array for this index yet which triggers the segmentation fault.

Also, as pointed out by @Jeffrey, since you construct a symmetric matrix you should only calculate the upper or lower triangular matrix

You can fix it by initializing you graph at the beginning and adding a condition on i and j:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int graph_size = 40;

int main(void)
{
    bool **graph;
    graph = new bool *[graph_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < graph_size; i++)
        graph[i] = new bool[graph_size];


    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < graph_size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < graph_size; j++)
        {
            if (i == j) graph[i][j] = false;
            else if (i < j) // limits to upper triangular matrix
            {
                graph[j][i] = (((rand() % 100) / 100.0) < 0.19);
                graph[i][j] = graph[j][i];
            }
            cout << graph[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, the output graph will not be the same as the generated one!! After `cout << graph[i][j];`, for some cell, the value will be changed by `graph[i][j] = graph[j][i]`